# Convexity of a set of constraints

Tags: convex-analysis

Given the equations
$||x||_2=1$, $\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i=0$ and some of the $y_i$ values sum to zero, e.g., $y_5+y_3+y_2=0$ is it possible to prove that the set $$\mathcal{Y} = \{ y~|~ ||x||_2=1, \sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i=0, \sum_{i\in\{5,3,2\}}y_i=0\}$$ is convex?

Comment: What is $x$? Is it given?

Comment: @daw $x$ is fixed vector with $||x||=1$.

Comment: In this case, $\mathcal Y$ is even a linear subspace.

Comment: @daw if we relax the constraint to $||x||\leq 1$ will that help to prove that $\mathcal{Y}$ is convex?